# Can't import disk image to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vmdk

I'm trying to import image to Google Cloud Platform from vmdk file:

```
gcloud compute images import jira-vmdk --source-file gs://r-vm/jira_0-flat.vmdk.gz --os debian-9
```

OS pre-verified by import_precheck utility:

[import_precheck screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq4KE.png)

But an error appears during import:

```
[import-and-translate.translate.translate-disk.wait-for-translator]: 2018-05-08T18:29:21Z WaitForInstancesSignal: instance "inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-t0013": watching serial port 1, SuccessMatch: "TranslateSuccess:", FailureMatch: "TranslateFailed:".
[import-and-translate]: 2018-05-08T18:31:51Z Error running workflow: step "translate" run error: step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-t0013": "TranslateFailed: error: inspect_vm: no operating systems found"
[import-and-translate]: 2018-05-08T18:31:51Z Workflow "import-and-translate" cleaning up (this may take up to 2 minutes).

[Daisy] Errors in one or more workflows:
  import-and-translate: step "translate" run error: step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-t0013": "TranslateFailed: error: inspect_vm: no operating systems found"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/daisy:release" failed: exit status 1
```

How can I fix it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image

> The bootloader on the boot disk must not have quiet, rhgb, or
>   splashimage= kernel command line arguments. Compute Engine does not
>   support splash screens on boot. You can remove these values from the
>   GRUB config during the bootloader configuration step.

steps for Debian 9

in /etc/default/grub

comment out

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

add

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0,38400n8d"

sudo update-grub
```